# GBM error in classification bernoulli distribution

Tags: r, gbm

When running the gbm function for a classification problem. I get the following error:

> Error in res[flag, ] <- predictions : replacement has length zero

I would like to know why I get this error and how to solve it.

My data is about 77 numeric variables(intergers) to be used in the classification and the 1 grouping factor. No other variables are in the data. There is no missing data in the data. The grouping factor is coded as a factor (0,1) as required.

The structure of my data looks something like this:

```
$Group : Factor w/ 2 levels "0", "1"
$it1 : int
...
$it70 : int
```

my model looks like this:

```
mod_gbm <- gbm(Group~. distribution = "bernoulli", data=df,
               n.trees=1000,shrinkage=.01, n.minobsinnode=5, 
               interaction.depth = 6, cv.folds=5)
```

I realize this question is very similar to the one here: 
[Problems in using GBM function to do classification in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615543/problems-in-using-gbm-function-to-do-classification-in-r)
but that person was wondering about using a numeric variable and the only response was to remove cv.folds. I would like to keep cv.folds in my model and to have it run.

Comment: Going to need to try and figure out if the issue is with your dataset or the gbm package. Does classification work for a single decision tree? Could you try a different package which has a boosting implementation? Is there any error when the model is trained?

Comment: I cannot run the model with 1 tree but I can run the gbm3 package with no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the vignette of `gbm`:

```
distribution: Either a character string specifying the name of the
          distribution to use or a list with a component ‘name’
          specifying the distribution and any additional parameters
          needed. If not specified, ‘gbm’ will try to guess: if the
          response has only 2 unique values, bernoulli is assumed;
          otherwise, if the response is a factor, multinomial is
          assumed
```

If you only have two classes, you don't need to convert it into a factor. We can explore this with iris example, where I create a group label 0/1 :

```
library(gbm)
df = iris
df$Group = factor(as.numeric(df$Species=="versicolor"))
df$Species = NULL
 
mod_gbm <- gbm(Group~.,distribution ="bernoulli", data=df,cv.folds=5)
Error in res[flag, ] <- predictions : replacement has length zero
```

I get the same error. So we convert it to numeric 0/1 and you can see it works correctly.

When the variable is a factor, doing `as.numeric()` converts it to 1,2 with 1 corresponding to the first level. So this case, since Group is 0/1 to start with:

```
df$Group = as.numeric(df$Group)-1
mod_gbm <- gbm(Group~.,distribution ="bernoulli", data=df,cv.folds=5)
```

And we get the predictions:

```
pred = ifelse(predict(mod_gbm,type="response")>0.5,1,0)
table(pred,df$Group)

    
pred  0  1
   0 98  3
   1  2 47
```